# Отслеживание объекта с камеры. Как лучше реализовать?

Tags: java, android, камера

Есть задача: Отследить нужную белую точку на белом фоне, их может быть несколько. 
Пользователь получает превью камеры, затем выбирает точку касанием и начинается отслеживание точки. Область тача задается квадратом 100х100, при этом точка движется с минимальной скоростью, не выходит за пределы квадрата (зоны тача). Я эту задачу разбил на маленькие подзадачи:

- Реализовать превью камеры +
- Узнать координаты касания, выделить область касания +
- Пробежаться по прямоугольнику 100х100 (область касания) найти самую яркую точку -
- Определить центр (максимальное значение интенсивности будет максимальным, т.к. белый цвет) -
- Получив координаты центра, построить прямоугольник от этой точки.-

Возникают проблемы с последними пунктами. Как их лучше реализовать? Задержка допустима.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Врятли это получится средствами java. Вернее может и получится - но производительность постоянного сканирования каждого кадра на определенную точку, её отслеживание и т.д. будет очень низкой. Вам придется делать это на с++ в NDK, либо использовать другие библиотеки: OpenCV (универсальная), Mobile vision от гугла (ограничена распознаванием лица, баркода, текста), и т.д. см. https://habr.com/ru/post/345268/

Как это возможно сделать на OpenCV:

1. при нажатии на превью сохранить ограничения (координаты) 100x100 в пределах которых нужно будет самую искать яркую точку
2. наложить на изображение нужные фильтры (первести в серый, сделать сглаживание по медиане что-бы устранить "шум" камеры, найти координаты самой яркой точки в пределах координат ранее сохраненного ограниченного прямоугольника 100x100)
3. нарисовать прямоугольник в пределах координат этой точки

Пункты 2. и 3. будут выполнятся для каждого кадра.

Тема не простая. Надо хорошо знать что вам нужно и что вы делаете.